# Strawberry Perl Memory Limit?

Tags: perl, memory, scripting

I'm running a perl script to pull a list of about 20 text files, and parse through them.  For some reason my process is bombing partway through the list, and am having trouble debugging it.

Anyone know the location of the Strawberry perl log file, and if there's a builtin max execution time, or memory limit variable like in PHP?

There are three files:
1. cron.php
2. nightly_script.php
3. myscript.pl

It successfully executes the first insert statement in that while loop, but not anymore after that.  Since this is running like a cron job I don't have any output window to look at.  This is why I was hoping there's a log somewhere, so if there's a syntax error, or a mysql error I can see it somewhere.  Also, if I just run myscript.pl on the file in question directly, it works no problem.

**cron.php**

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

/*

min hr dom month dow cmd

hour in 24 hour format, no leading zeros


*/

$jobsQueue = Array();

$jobsQueue[] = Array('10', '0', '*', '*', '*', 'php c:\nightly_script.php');    // These items are order dependent, so run as one script that synchronously executes each command

while(1) {

    $now = time();
    $min = date('i',$now);
    $hr = date('G',$now);

    echo "$hr:$min\n";

    foreach($jobsQueue AS $job) {

        if($job[0] == $min && $job[1] == $hr) {
            system("$job[5]>NULL");
        }

    }

    sleep(60);
}
?>
```

**nightly_script.php**

```
// Process Hand Histories
system('perl myscript.pl');

?>
```

**myscript snippet**

```
while ( ($key, $value) = each(%players) ) {
                print "$key => $value\n";
                if($value > 0)
                {
                    $uname = $key;
                    $uname =~ s/player(.*)(\s*)/$1/;

                    $connect = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$config_mysql_db;host=$config_mysql_server",$config_mysql_user,$config_mysql_pass,{'RaiseError' => 1});

                    print "\n*****\n$uname\n*****\n";

                    $updateStatement = "INSERT statement";
                    $executeStatement = $connect->prepare($updateStatement);
                    $executeStatement->execute();

                    $updateStatement = "UPDATE command";
                    $executeStatement = $connect->prepare($updateStatement);
                    $executeStatement->execute();

                    delete $players{$key};
                    # Clean up the record set and the database connection
                    $connect->disconnect(); 

                }
                elsif($value <= 0)
                {
                    delete $players{$key};
                }
            }
```

Comment: Well, perl is different than PHP there is no "log file" like the "error_log" in php or those memory/time limits. We need to have more information on what your code is doing (code sample) and what you mean by "bombing"? If it just stops executing the script, perl is certainly printing something out.

Comment: Hmm, so the only errors I'll get such as syntax errors and the like will be to stdout?

Comment: Yes - on `stderr` to be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since perl doesn't have a log like php, you can create your own log file by redirecting perl's stdout and stderr to a file. Try doing this by modifying the system call in `nightly_script.php`.

```
system('perl myscript.pl 1>myperllog.txt 2>&1');
```

or

```
system('perl myscript.pl 1>myperllog.txt 2>myperllog.err');
```

Comment: nice, that's pretty helpful, though I'm quite surprised there's no builtin perl error log.  Guess I need to branch out more :)

Comment: You probably don't want to miss the stderr either. Capture that with `... 2> myperllog.err` or `... 2>&1`.

Comment: @JohnZ: Thats what `stdout` and `stderr` are for and not to have a builtin log honors the unix way. You still can do whatever you need with those streams.

Comment: Sweet that worked like a charm.  Ah, so I guess that makes sense on using stdout and stderr to reuse functionality across multiple software programs.  Thanks everyone!